# how can i set max char while using AngularJS on iphone

Tags: iphone, angularjs, text, textbox, maxlength

im trying to set the max char in the textbox

```
            <form class="form-horizontal">
            <input type="text" ng-model="formtodotext" ng-model-instant maxlength="22">
            <button class="btn btn-info"ng-click="addTodo()"><i class="icon-plus"></i>Toevoegen</button>
           </form>
```

but it doesn't work on iphone, in chrome it does

PS: max="22" doesn't work either

Sorry if i wrote this wrong, stack overflow noob..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to just mark an input as invalid if typed text is longer than 22, you can use `ng-pattern`:

```
<input type="text" ng-pattern="/^.{0,22}$/" ng-model="formtodotext" ng-model-instant>
```

Preventing user input if he tries to type 23rd character needs a custom directive:

```
app.directive('maxLength',function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, el, attrs, ngModelCtrl){
      function checkLength(text) {
        var old = ngModelCtrl.$modelValue;
        if(text.length<=attrs.maxLength) {
          return text;
        }else{
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(old);
          ngModelCtrl.$render();
          return old;
        }
      }
      ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(checkLength);
    }
  }
});
```

Use it like that:

```
<input type="text" max-length="22" ng-model="formtodotext" ng-model-instant>
```

Comment: +1 for basically answering my question at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19512029/can-i-use-ngmodelcontrollers-formatter-to-fully-control-how-an-input-field-is/ with your custom directive example.

Comment: Works but had to change max-length="22" to maxlength="22"

Comment: Actually, `maxlength` is a built-in HTML input attribute, totally forgot about it. Still, this directive works, but you use it through setting `max-length`: http://plnkr.co/edit/6OdfGhNb9poGkdpGhp1o

Answer (score 0):

I would expect maxlength to work on iOS as well as chrome. You don't need to use ng-pattern for this there's an ng-maxlength. It marks the form as invalid but it doesn't stop the user entering more text.

`<input type="text" ng-model="formtodotext" ng-model-instant ng-maxlength="22" maxlength="22">`