# Can I use ngModelController's $formatter to fully control how an input field is rendered?

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to make an input that simulates `type="number"` but I want to add my own buttons to it. Basically I've made

```
<form name="fasdf">
    <button class="btn" ng-click="decrement()">&#9668;</button>
    <input type="text" ng-model="model" display-as-number />
    <button class="btn" ng-click="increment()">&#9658;</button>
</form>
```

I'm using `input type="text"` because I don't want the user agent to add it's own buttons to the field.

It should be possible to use the `input` itself to enter a value as well as using the buttons to increment or decrement the value.

```
angular.module('app',[])
.controller('Ctrl', ['$scope', function($scope) {

  $scope.model = 0;

  $scope.decrement = function() {
    $scope.model--;
  };

  $scope.increment = function() {
    $scope.model++;
  };

}])
```

The value is initially `0` but when the user starts entering text I want any leading zeros to be stripped as they type (well, actually the suits want that but you get my drift).

My theory was that I could use a `$formatter` and/or a `$parser` to do this by making a directive that accesses the `ngModelController`.

```
angular.module('app')
.directive('displayAsNumber', [function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel',
    link: function(scope, element, attrs, controller) {

        controller.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
            var value = parseInt(modelValue, 10);
            return value;
        });

        controller.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
            var value = parseInt(viewValue, 10);
            return value;
        });          
    };
}]);
```

But while the `$formatter` is being run every time I type something in the input, it is not overriding the actual value of the input field, in other words it is not stripping any leading zeros.

I can get this working by listening on DOM events (although I can't change the value on each keyup as that will move the cursor to the end of the field) by replacing the directive body with

```
element.on('focus', function() {
  var value = parseInt(element.val(), 10);
  if (value === 0)
    element.val('');
});

element.on('focusout', function() {
  if ('' === element.val().trim())
    element.val(0);
  else
    element.val(parseInt(element.val(), 10));
});
```

The resulting behaviour is good enough (it blanks out the field on focus if the value is `0` and strips leading `0s` on focusout.

Question is, is there any way I could have achieved this behaviour without adding event-listeners to `element`?
How do I properly control how the input is rendered using `ngModelController`?

Plnkr: http://plnkr.co/edit/YOkFGNGamfA1Xb9pOP1U?p=preview

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, yeah, after looking at other new questions I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19511588/how-can-i-set-max-char-while-using-angularjs-on-iphone) and realized I was simply missing a call to `controller.$render()`

```
controller.$parsers.push(function (viewValue) {
  var value = parseInt(viewValue, 10);
  controller.$viewValue = value;
  controller.$render();
  return value;
});
```

Fixes my problem. I'll go away now.

Comment: Odd. According to the documentation, [`$render()`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel.NgModelController#methods_$render) is a user-defined function. You're not defining it, so what is it actually doing?

Comment: I am using the input directive here, so it's defined by that. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0-rc.3/src/ng/directive/input.js#L442